Text color isn't getting changed
I am writing a simple script for a js counter that increments or decrements the count everything is working fine but the text color isn't getting changed, I want the color to be red if the count is negative and green if it's positive here's my script:


let counting = document.getElementById("counting");
let increaseBtn = document.getElementById("increase-btn");
let decreaseBtn = document.getElementById("decrease-btn");
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-btn");
let value = document.getElementById("value")
let counter = 0;

increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    counting.innerHTML = ++counter;
    updateColor();

    

});
decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    counting.innerHTML = --counter;
    updateColor();
    

});
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    counting.innerHTML = counter = 0;
    updateColor();
});

function updateColor(){
    if(counter > 0){
        value.style.color = "green";
    }
    else if(counter < 0){
        value.style.color = "red";
    }
    else {
        value.style.color = "black";
    }
}
<div>Counter: <span id="counting"></span></div>
<input type="button" id="increase-btn" value="+">
<input type="button" id="decrease-btn" value="-">
<input type="button" id="reset-btn" value="Reset">
<div>Value: <span id="value">some value here</span></div>




You should add the HTML so it's easier to reason about and proffer solution.

Your code looks fine

^^ I've made reasonable guesses at the HTML and updated the question with a Stack Snippet. As you can see, the code works. Could it be you don't have anything in the id="value" element? (So you don't see any color change.) Or did you mean to style the id="counting" element? Are the ids right? Perhaps one or more elements were missing? Were there any errors in the console? In any case, please edit the snippet in the question so that it replicates the problem you're having.

@Danish Check your HTML, maybe one of the IDs doesn't match the ones in the JS code.

    let counting = document.getElementById("counting");
    let increaseBtn = document.getElementById("increase-btn");
    let decreaseBtn = document.getElementById("decrease-btn");
    let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-btn");
    let value = document.getElementById("value");
    let counter = 0;
    increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        counting.innerHTML = ++counter;
        updateColor();
    });

    decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        counting.innerHTML = --counter;
        updateColor();
    });

    resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        counting.innerHTML = counter = 0;
        updateColor();
    });

    // Function to update color based on counter value
    function updateColor() {
        if (counter > 0) {
            counting.style.color = "green";
        } else if (counter < 0) {
            counting.style.color = "red";
        } else {
            counting.style.color = "black";
        }
    }

Use the counting variable instead of the value under the updateColor() function, and all is working fine. I tested it and it's working fine.
Click here check the output
